# How to call a stored procedure within a SELECT query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a store procedure that takes in a uniqueidentifier and returns a table. What I am trying to do is to use these results like a regular table, but I realize SQL is still limited and doesn't allow it (yet!)

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable MT
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT *
     FROM MyStoredProc(MT.ID) MSP
     WHERE MT.SomeData = MSP.SomeData)
```

Is there an alternative solution to this problem? And please don't suggest using a function or a view as they are not exchangeable with a stored procedure. I'm actually quite surprised that the developers haven't implemented this yet considering the age of SQL.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: If you can't turn it into a table-valued function, the only other alternative you really have is to insert the results of the stored procedure into a temp table, and then utilize that temp table.

Comment: The problem with that is that the stored procedure takes a parameter that is defined as a value in the MyTable table. Sadly SQL doesn't let you fill/overwrite temp tables with this syntax.

Comment: Then you need to rewrite the stored procedure to dump a table with 'every possible parameter value' to a table. I'm sorry, but there's just really no other way to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

That syntax won't work. You'd have to dump the results of the stored proc into a temp table and the reference the temp table.
Because Of the parameter, I'd suggest either making a new version of the proc that can execute for all IDs at once or drop the proc code into a table valued function (which can be executed using the syntax you're trying to use).

Comment: The stored procedure requires dynamic SQL, which apparently isn't implemented for table valued functions, so that isn't an option.

Comment: You are correct... No dynamic SQL is allowed in t-sql functions. Are you able to write a 2nd version of the dynamic proc that can process all rows in "MyTable" all at once? If so, that would beat the heck out of using a loop to execute the proc for every unique ID in MyTable.

Comment: I won't go into the details of the stored proc, but the names of columns that get selected are dynamically based on the ID that is passed as a parameter (via some other SELECT statements). Thus, the proc cannot be extended beyond a single ID unless I loop though every ID, and use UNION ALL to join them, which ain't much better than just looping here anyway.